Any way to change Log directory on IIS 10? via Registry?
We're constantly getting incident tickets for server OS disk full, we want to push all IIS log files to a secondary drive. I can do this in the UI but I want to automate the change so the process can be automated when building new servers.
IIS 10 for Windows Server 2019. The closest I came to was using the "Remote Administration for IIS Manager" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/general/use-registry-keys
But with the role added and the WMSVC service started, I cannot seem to change the log directory via registry.
Anyone might have an idea or is this just going to have to be a manual step every time?

Questions about server administration are off topic here. Besides, IIS configuration allows you to move the log directory of site defaults to another drive if you automate the changes during OS deployment, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/sitedefaults/logfile/#configuration, not via registry keys. Note that this affects only new sites created after the change. Existing sites need to be reconfigured.

To automate the process of moving IIS log files to a secondary drive during server builds, you can use a PowerShell script.

You can use AppCmd.exe
AppCmd.exe set config -section:system.applicationHost/sites /siteDefaults.logFile.directory:"<Directory>" /commit:apphost

Or you can use PowerShell
Import-Module WebAdministration
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -Filter 'system.applicationHost/sites/siteDefaults/logFile' -Name 'directory' -Value '<Directory>'

See also PowerShell command to set IIS logging settings.
